# Question Regarding Drupal 7 Slideshow

Tags: drupal-7

I  please need help regarding this problem of mine. Its in Drupal 7

I have six albums and in my slideshow i need the cover of the albums to rotate in the slideshow by default.

Later when the user clicks on a particular album which are thumbnails below the slideshow that particular album which has been clicked upon has to rotate
in the slideshow replacing the old one. And each album contains 25 images.

Regards
 Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You could think about using this module for Drupal 7,
http://drupal.org/node/755010.
And looking into this tutorial and modify it to suit your needs,
http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42.